# How to stop propagation of events of Swiper.JS?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Swiper Element in a React app as described here: https://swiperjs.com/blog/using-swiper-element-in-react

In this app, we have a top menu bar that is hidden by default and should appear (toggle) if the user clicks/touches anywhere on the page. But of course if the click/touch is executing any other event, the menu bar should not be toggled.

For example: A click/touch just in the middle of the image (in a slide of Slider.js) should toggle the visibility of the menu bar. But a swipe to the next slide or a click on the navigation arrows or pagination buttons should not toggle the visibility of the menu bar.

Is there a way to capture those Swiper events and do `e.stopPropagation()`?